# Is there any tool out there for generating elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

Mostly what I do is to assemble the mapping by hand. Choosing the correct types myself.
Is there any tool which facilitates this?

For example which will read a class (c#,java..etc) and choosing the closest ES types accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen such a tool, however I know that ElasticSearch has a REST API over HTTP.

So you can create a simple HTTP query with JSON body that will depict *your* object with *your* fields: field names + types (Strings, numbers, booleans) - pretty much like a Java/C# class that you've described in the question.

Then you can ask the ES to store the data in the non-existing index (to "index" your document in ES terms). It will index the document, but it will also create an index, and the most importantly for your question, will create a mapping for you "dynamically", so that later you will be able to query the mapping structure (again via REST).

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) is the link to the relevant chapter about dynamically created mappings in the ES documentation

And [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) you can find the API for querying the mapping structure

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day you'd still want to retain some control over how your mapping is generated. I'd recommend:

1. syncing some sample documents w/o a mapping
2. investigating what mapping was auto generated and
3. dropping the index & using [dynamic_templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) to pseudo-auto-generate / update the mapping as new documents come in.

This [GUI](https://github.com/appbaseio/gem) could help too.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no such tool available to generate the mapping for elastic.
It is a kind of similar thing as we have to design a database in MySQL.
But if we want such kind of thing then we use Mongo DB which requires no predefined schema.

But Elastic comes with its very dynamic feature, which allows us to play around it. One of the most important features of Elasticsearch is that it tries to get out of your way and let you start exploring your data as quickly as possible like the mongo schema which can be manipulated dynamically.

To index a document, you don’t need to first define a mapping or schema and define your fields along with their data type .
You can just index a document and the index, type, and fields will be created automatically.

For further details you can go through the below documentation:

[Elastic Dynamic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html)